# PHP Infinite loop till condition met

Tags: php, curl, logic

Not sure I caught some brain stunt but just can't brain on how to proceed.

I have a bunch of code and realise later that I need to put them into a infinite loop. The objective curl-> process data -> if "next url" is not empty, loop do the curl again.

Current Situation:

```
// Call curl function here and bind to variable $result
$result = curl_blabla;

// Process data
....
....

// Check next url
if(!empty($result->next_url)){}  // Failed to brain how to do infinite loop here.
```

Comment: it's a simple recursive logic, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
while (true) {
    $result = curl_blabla;
    // Process data
    ....
    ....
    // Check next url
    if(empty($result->next_url)){ break; } 
}
```

Or this:

```
$has_next_url = true;
while ($has_next_url) {
    $result = curl_blabla;
    // Process data
    ....
    ....
    // Check next url
    $has_next_url = empty($result->next_url);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the first solution seems to be more professional and clean.

Answer (score 3):

Recursive call of a function:

```
function loadURL($url) {
  // curl stuff, handle is $ch
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  if(!empty($result->next_url)) {
    loadURL($result->next_url);
  }
}

loadURL($initial_url);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 while(!$whatIDontHaveYet){
   $IHaveIt = true;
   // ... process data
   $whatIDontHaveYet = $IHaveIt;
 }
```

A while loop does what you said in title.